# How are the category id of app notification determined on ANCS?

Tags: ios, ancs

I know that LINE, Facebook Messanger belong to CategoryIDSocial.
How does the category id determine?
Can an app developer define it?

Category ID List
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Appendix/Appendix.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH3-SW1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like they are defined by Apple so you would have no control over it.

Could it loosely be tied to the AppStore categories you have to choose when submitting application to AppStore?

http://blog.sensortower.com/blog/2013/09/30/the-ios-developers-guide-to-apple-app-store-categories/